# Is it necessary to use a temporary variable when setting a properties' value?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a (retained) UIImage property that is being used to hold a user selected image.

This is the code I have at present when the user makes a selection:

```
- (IBAction) selectImage1 {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"image1-big.png"];
    self.bigImage = image;
}
```

but I'm wondering if it is possible to omit the use of the temporary variable convenience method and just do this:

```
- (IBAction) selectImage1 {
    self.bigImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"image1-big.png"];
}
```

If there are problems with this second method (I'm guessing something to do with memory management), could someone please explain?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way is perfectly fine. The line `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"image1-big.png"];` gives you a variable `image` that is auto-released. Assigning it to your ivar via the `self.bigImage = image` calls `bigImage`'s setter method which retains the value. Thus the line `self.bigImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"image1-big.png"];` is equivalent to the more verbose way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in terms of memory management between the two snippets you posted; unless you get really specific about retain counts in between the two lines in the first snippet.

In an ARC environment, the local variable will be a 'strong' pointer, however it is released when the method leaves scope. In the second snippet, there is no intermediate retain/release'd pointer, and so may actually be slightly more efficient.

The places I have seen the first snippet's technique be necessary are when you have a weak pointer (i.e. a weak @property) where setting `self.foo = [UIView ...` would immediately allow it to be released. In these cases it is better to use a local variable to keep it around while you work with it:

```
UIView *someFoo = [UIView...
[self addSubview:someFoo];
self.someWeakProperty = someFoo;
```

compare with:

```
self.someWeakProperty = [UIView...
[self addSubview:self.someWeakProperty]; // it's already nil!!
```